# Two members of a group can't view list items in sharepoint 2010

Tags: list, permissions, site

I created a list on a top-level site. The list inherits permissions from the site. All members of the group share the same contribute-level permission. I have checked all views and all list items, and everything indicates that permissions are inherited.

Two members of the group are able to see the list, but not the list items. All other members can see all list items. I have checked Active Directory, and nothing seems to set these two individuals apart from the rest of the team.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

Try using Check Permissions in Permissions Management Page at List level and Item Level. Try checking the two users and another who can see the items to ensure they all have the same permissions.

You can also look what values has the list item-level permissions at List Configuration -> Advanced settings.